# Creating schema via declarative mapping: Base.metadata.create_all(engine) does not work

Tags: python, mysql, sqlalchemy

Here is an absurd problem with sqlalchemy that seems easy! First, this is my config file for connecting to [mysql](/questions/tagged/mysql) database:

```
from sqlalchemy import create_engine
from sqlalchemy.ext.declarative import declarative_base
Base = declarative_base()
engine = create_engine('mysql://root:@localhost:3306/digi')
```

and then, I am trying to create a table called 'sale-history' :

```
from config import *
from sqlalchemy import *

class Sale(Base):
    __tablename__ = 'sale-history'
    order_id = column(Integer, primary_key= True)
    customer_id = column(Integer)
    item_id = column(Integer)       #froeign key with product list
    cartFinalize_dateTime = column(DATETIME)
    amount_ordrered = column(Integer)
    city_name = column(String(191))
    quantity_ordered = column(Integer)

    def __repr__(self):
        return "<Sale(city_name='%s')>" % (self.city_name)

Sale.__table__
Base.metadata.create_all(engine)
```

Now, what I wonder is that

```
Sale.__table__
```

and

```
Base.metadata.create_all(engine)
```

are not known to my code. More accurate, these are not in suggestion options showed by pycharm editor. Debugging the code does not throw any error(returns 0). What should I do to create tables?
I appreciate your consideration so much!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The code is using `column` to define columns in the table but it should be using `Column` (note the upper-case "C").

A few tips/comments

- Pycharm may provide better support if you avoid the `from module import *` idiom. You can alias module names if they are to long to type, for example `import sqlalchemy as sa`
- You can see the SQL generated by the engine by passing `echo=True` to `create_engine`
- Tablenames with hyphens need to be quoted with backticks to be valid.  Sqlalchemy does this automatically, but other applications may not. Using underscores instead may be more convenient.

The final code might look like this:

config

```
from sqlalchemy import create_engine
from sqlalchemy.ext.declarative import declarative_base

Base = declarative_base()
engine = create_engine('mysql://root:@localhost:3306/test', echo=True)
```

Model

```
import sqlachemy as sa
import config


class Sale(Base): 
    __tablename__ = 'sale-history'
    order_id = sa.Column(sa.Integer, primary_key=True)
    customer_id = sa.Column(sa.Integer)   
    item_id = sa.Column(sa.Integer)       # foreign key with product list
    cartFinalize_dateTime = sa.Column(sa.DATETIME)
    amount_ordrered = sa.Column(sa.Integer)
    city_name = sa.Column(sa.String(191))
    quantity_ordered = sa.Column(sa.Integer)

    def __repr__(self):
        return "<Sale(city_name='%s')>" % (self.city_name)


Base.metadata.create_all(config.engine)
```